# Zero padding inside of Pandas bins

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, padding

I have a Pandas data frame `df` that looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Group": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"], 
                       "Index": [1, 8, 9, 1, 3], 
                       "Value": [23.2, 1.2, 1.7, 21.9, 432.2]})
>>> print(df)

  Group  Index  Value
0     a      1   23.2
1     a      8    1.2
2     a      9    1.7
3     b      1   21.9
4     b      3  432.2
```

I would like to obtain the following (blank lines are for illustration purposes):

```
  Group  Index   Value
0     a      1   23.2
1     a      2    0.0
2     a      3    0.0

3     a      7    0.0
4     a      8    1.2
5     a      9    1.7

6     b      1   21.9
7     b      2    0.0
8     b      3  432.2
```

Essentially I would like to introduce zero padding inside the "Value" column so that all "Index" bins [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] and [7, 8, 9] are filled with exactly 3 values. "Index" integers can only appear once inside a group and can range from 1 to 9. If a bin doesn't contain any "Index" integer, no padding should take place. Rows of "Group a" and "Group b" should be processed independently.

This is how far I got:

```
a_group = df.groupby("Group")
for _, group in a_group:
    group["Bin"] = pd.cut(group["Index"], bins=list(range(1, 12, 3)), right=False)
    print(group)
    print("\n")

  Group  Index  Value      Bin
0     a      1   23.2   [1, 4)
1     a      8    1.2  [7, 10)
2     a      9    1.7  [7, 10)


  Group  Index  Value     Bin
3     b      1   21.9  [1, 4)
4     b      3  432.2  [1, 4)
```

At this point I don't know what else to do and would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your expected output - where are the values for index `4,5,6` for group `a`? are those supposed to be missing?

Comment: Your problem definition isn't clear, why `1,2,3` but `7,8,9`, not `8,9,10`?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for answering. As I mentioned, if no value is inside one bin no padding should take place. '4,5,6' do not exist in group 'a'.
*Alright, sorry. So the bins have an interval length of 3. But the values can be any integers ranging from 1-9. E.g. 5 is part of the 4,5,6 bin, but does not exist in this particular df. So no padding should take place in 4,5,6. Also, values can only appear once inside a group.

Comment: Given your example in your comment could a 3,4,5 bin exist? Or bins could only be [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]?

Comment: Only [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]. Thanks for asking. Should have made it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
g = df['Group'].unique()
i = range(1,df['Index'].max()+1)

df2 = df.set_index(['Group','Index']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([g,i])).assign(cc = lambda x: (x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())//3).rename_axis(['Group','Index'],axis=0)
df2.loc[~df2['Value'].isna().groupby([pd.Grouper(level=0),df2['cc']]).transform('all')].reset_index().fillna(0).drop('cc',axis=1)
```

Comment: YES! It's perfect. I will have to get behind what exactly happens in your code but it does what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by @rhug123 is a pretty good one, but I propose an alternative solution below. The core idea of my solution is to create a bin identifier/key that will help select the target Indexes.

### **TL;DR**

```
max_index_value = 9
bin_size = 3

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({"Group":np.repeat(df['Group'].unique(), max_index_value)})
df_temp['Index'] = df_temp.groupby(['Group']).cumcount() + 1
df_temp = df_temp.merge(df, how='left', on=['Group', 'Index'])
df_temp['bin_key'] = df_temp.groupby(['Group']).cumcount() // bin_size

df_bin_key = df_temp.groupby(['Group', 'bin_key'])[['Value']].max().reset_index().dropna().drop(columns=['Value'])

df_final = df_bin_key.merge(df_temp, how='left', on=['Group', 'bin_key']).fillna(0).drop(columns=['bin_key'])
```

### **Step-by-step explanation.**

Start by essentially creating a temporary dataframe that will serve as a placeholder for missing index values of the original `df`.

```
max_index_value = 9
bin_size = 3

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({"Group":np.repeat(df['Group'].unique(), max_index_value)})
df_temp['Index'] = df_temp.groupby(['Group']).cumcount() + 1

# getting the values from original dataset
df_temp = df_temp.merge(df, how='left', on=['Group', 'Index'])
```

Next, add the bin key that will serve to mark the bins for later grouping.

```
# the bin size defines the available key values
df_temp['bin_key'] = df_temp.groupby(['Group']).cumcount() // bin_size
```

```
Group      Index       bin_key   Value
a          1           0            23.2
a          2           0            NaN
a          3           0            NaN
a          4           1            NaN
.          .           .            .
.          .           .            .
.          .           .            .
b          6           1            NaN
b          7           2            NaN
b          8           2            NaN
b          9           2            NaN
```

Then, here is the tricky part where we use the group function on the columns `Group` and `bin_key` with a `max()` function to select which Groups and keys should be present in the final result.

```
df_bin_key = df_temp.groupby(['Group', 'bin_key'])[['Value']].max().reset_index().dropna().drop(columns=['Value'])
```

```
Group   bin_key
a       0
a       2
b       0
```

Finally, we reach the desired results by left joining `df_temp` into `df_bin_key` using the `Group` and `bin keys`.

```
df_final = df_bin_key.merge(df_temp, how='left', on=['Group', 'bin_key']).fillna(0).drop(columns=['bin_key'])
```

```
Group   Index   Value
a       1       23.2
a       2       0.0
a       3       0.0
a       7       0.0
a       8       1.2
a       9       1.7
b       1       21.9
b       2       0.0
b       3       432.2
```

PS: I broke this solution down into various steps for explanatory purposes, some steps here can be rewritten and combined into one-liners.

Comment: Hey, muito obrigado. @rhug123 gave me a quick solution but somehow it didn't work on my actual dataset (this one was just exemplary). Your code works fine but for a larger data frame I'm getting double/triple/multiple "Index" integers inside one group. Trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Okay, so my data set has a problem. I have two groups instead of one, so if I only use one group I get non-unique "index" integers. I'll try to fix this.

Comment: @SandorAlbert What do you mean by multiple "index" integers, do you mean that for a given Group value the Index value can repeat itself (for instance the value 'a' be related to more than one '1' Index)? Can you give an example? In this example that you provided, there are two `Group` values (`a` and `b`) so what do you mean by two groups instead of one?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant by two groups is two group columns. If so, if you apply your or @rhug123 code, you will get non-unique "Index" entries. I was able to solve the problem by simply adding the second group column to @rhug123 code:

`g = df['Group1'].unique()
h = df['Group2'].unique()
i = range(1,df['Index'].max()+1)`

and changing the respective parts of his code.

Comment: @SandorAlbert good, glad you solved your issue =)

Comment: Thanks again and many regards to Brazil :)

Comment: @SandorAlbert Thank you, we are in terrible need of good vibes right now in Brazil #nervouslaugh. Where are you from?